# Color Dark Appearance in Xcode 12 - SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, xcode12

I have the following code:

```
.background(Color("Bg").ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .all))
```

which would work before the new dark mode implementation, but now I have 2 sets for each theme which is great:

[image]

How can I call the dark appearance color in my code above?

Thanks

Comment: You don't need to do that manually, once system appearance changed corresponding variant of color will be used automatically.

Comment: Oh, that's even better! waoh! Nice. If you want put that in the answer so I can close this. Thanks Asperi